# How to assign a style using sheet['A'].style/styleObj after styleObj has been assigned in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

## Problem with sheet['A'].style/styleObj in Python 2.7

## What might be wrong?

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font, NamedStyle
# create new file
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
# read active sheet
sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()
# give new name parameters 
italic24Font = Font(size=24, italic=True)
styleObj = NamedStyle(font=italic24Font)
sheet['A'].style/styleObj
sheet['A1'] = 'Hello world!'
```

Comment: Should read `sheet['A1'].style = styleObj`. Read about [Named Style](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#creating-a-named-style)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help.
I found a correct version of the code:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font, NamedStyle
# create new file
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
# read active sheet
sheet = wb['Sheet']

# give new name parameters 
italic24Font = NamedStyle(name="italic24Font")
italic24Font.font = Font(size=24, italic=True)
sheet['A1'].style = italic24Font
sheet['A1'] = 'Hello world!'
```